# Git show remote branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I push a new branch to gitlab server:

```
git push -u origin release:release
```

operation succeeds and a new branch release do added on gitlab server.
Then I run locally:

```
git branch -r
```

turns out:

```
origin/HEAD->origin/master
origin/develop
origin/master
```

can not find origin/release.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you do a git pull to download changes?

Comment: Or you can use `git fetch` to get the remote changes without merging.

Comment: `git pull` or `git fetch` do not work

Comment: @SatanZ what do you mean? Remember, we're not next to you. You're going to need to give more information.